# How do you guys think about this RS-422 communication issue?

Tags: serial-port, hardware, noise-reduction, industrial

*Stack-overflow*!

I've an issue about the RS-422 communication within each devices in multi-drop environment.
And I also tried to solve this problem. Unfortunately, IT COULD NOT SOLVE BY MYSELF FOR ABOUT ONE YEAR!

So finally, Here to request for you guys help.

[Working Surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Bq7.png)

> We are using the same source code Model-A and Model-B (Data
>   Collector). However, as Model-A became obsoleted, We should make the
>   hardware for Model-B ourselves. As a result, Model-A and Model-B have
>   different hardware each other.
>
> Model-B was working very well for about one or two years.
>
> Nowadays, Model-A is still working fine. But, Model-B has something weird errors.
>   We've think these are about the RS-422 hardware issues. And We cannot identify why they caused, exactly.

The issues what we found:

1. The Model-B could not find to a device of connected. (However, It often be solved by disconnect manually the first device or second device.)
2. Receiving data stream from first and second device are swapped. (other device's packet found in own device's) (~5%)
3. Sometimes (~80%) Receiving data has some meaningless null bytes. like this.

   > - Proper receiving data: 01 04 04 00 00 45 92 48 B9 (9 bytes)
   > - With meaningless null bytes: 00 00 00 01 04 04 09 0C 48 CF 4E 4F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (22 bytes)

Please help me to escape this dizzy. thanks.

Comment: If I had to bet, it's a hardware issue.

Comment: I need to the also how we try to close this issues. 
So I want to hear about the general way to get the lead.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz Could I get your help about how to identify to these issues?

Comment: How would anyone help you if you don't show code and schematics? Please be kind enough to supply some of it, or at least the suspicious parts.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz Okay, I see. We would do try to find and upload that. thanks to advice.